# Equivalent of mono_string_to_utf8() without allocation and data copy

Tags: c#, c, mono

I am trying to replace the `C` code below by something more efficient:

```
void mstr2str(MonoString *mstr)
{
   char *str = mono_string_to_utf8(mstr);
   printf("mono string: %s\n", str);
   g_free(str);
}
```

My goal is to avoid the memory allocation and data copy that comes with mono_string_to_utf8() because the string returned by C# to C can be very large.

I have read the suggestions about using Windows C++ COM interfaces but being under Linux I try to use a direct way to address the `monostring` from C.

The reference below indicates that this is "*impossible*":

http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries#marshal-step-4

> *"there is no way to control how the runtime allocates the marshaled memory, or how long it lasts. This is crucial. If the runtime marshals
>   a string (e.g. UTF-16 to Ansi conversion), the marshaled string will
>   only last as long as the call. The unmanaged code CANNOT keep a
>   reference to this memory, as it WILL be freed after the call ends.
>   Failure to heed this restriction can result in "strange behavior",
>   including memory access violations and process death".*

But the subject is later addressed with `Marshalling`, `inPtr`, and `SafeHandles` in the same document (without ready-to-use examples while the reference blogs are from 2004/2005).

Any more up-to-date documentation or code examples available?

---

Thank you for the solution Lupus. For those who, like me, don't know C#, these calls are macros defined in a file called `object.h` and therefore they are reported as unresolved symbols if you load the runtime dynamically. Here they are:

```
#define mono_string_chars(s) ((gunichar2*)(s)->chars)
#define mono_string_length(s) ((s)->length)
```

It seems that C# uses pointers finally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That documentation is about marshaling on P/Invoke, which is a different topic, unrelated to the C code you're showing.

As for your question: you can access the string characters and do what you want with them by using mono_string_chars() and mono_string_length(). For example you could use iconv() which is available on Linux and OSX, or you can manually convert from UTF16 to UTF8 for maximum control.